# Redis Connection Timeout :Protocol error from client:

Tags: timeout, redis

We are performing Set Operations on Redis to extract and filter data for targeting. The sets are namely represented in the following manner

```
fruits={'orange','lemon','apple'}
vegetables={'tomato'}
citric={'orange','lemon','tomato'}
```

We are using the Jedis client to do SUNION and SINTER,  howerver what we have observed that evening with a concurrency of 100 the Redis Service returns time outs even with simple opration like
SMEMBERS
The set contains not more than 7 items

```
jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
jedisPoolConfig.maxActive = 1000;//Arguably High
jedisPoolConfig.minIdle = 300;//Arguably High
jedisPoolConfig.maxIdle = 500; //Arguably High
jedisPool = new JedisPool(jedisPoolConfig, "localhost", 6379, 1000);
jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
availableAds = new ArrayList<String>( jedis.smembers("fruits"));
jedisPool.returnResource(jedis);
```

## Java Exception

> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException :  It seems
>   like server has closed the connection.

## Redis Error Log

> Protocol error from client: addr=x.x.x.x:xxxx fd=270 idle=0 flags=N
>   db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=96 obl=47 oll=0 events=rw cmd=smembers
>
> The test was run on Amazon EC2 Medium Instance (C1.medium) and the
>   servlet was testing with blitz.io as the load testing tool

Comment: Protocol errors usually indicate a problem with threading. How are you achieving the "concurrency of 100"? Are you creating threads? Can you paste the relevant code?

Comment: maybe you should tell us what verion of jedis an redis you are using.

Comment: Hi Guys , the previous problem has been sorted,it seems that the pool was not released correctly, however we have come across a new problem, with 10 items in the set we were not getting any timeouts, however with 1000 items and 200 concurrency for a duration of 1 minute the timeouts goes sky rocket, the concurrency was tested using http://blitz.io/ they use tools like apache bench and siege to simulate load